# Child View Controller and Margin

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, childviewcontroller

I have a child view controller as below.

```
import UIKit
class SampleChildViewController : UIViewController {

    let imageView : UIImageView = {
        let imageview = UIImageView()
        imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageview.clipsToBounds = true
        imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageview.image = UIImage(named: "cat")
        return imageview
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(imageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
            ])
    }


}
```

then I have my parent view controller like below. I have added the child view controller into the parent view controller as shown below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let child : SampleChildViewController = SampleChildViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        child.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addChild(child)
        view.addSubview(child.imageView)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)

    }


}
```

Now the problem is I have a strange margin problem in the parent view controller for the image view. As you can see in the screenshot below, the image view is hidden behind the navigation bar. If I make the child view controller as the root view controller and load the application, then the image view is positioned correctly. How to over come this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give the child view neither a frame nor constraints

```
child.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Also you should add view not imageView

```
view.addSubview(child.view) 
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   child.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8),
   child.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
   child.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
   child.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
])
```

and set

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

Comment: this is kind of works but there is an unnecessary top margin between the navigation bar and the image view.

Comment: @JayMayu yes there is a margin. Do you know how to remove it? https://imgur.com/a/0S16Lf7

Comment: my auto layout goes as below `NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            child.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            child.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            child.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            child.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
            ])`